# REST API does not recognize polish chars properly?

Tags: rest, utf-8

we're using Drools Guvnor in our project and we're using rest api to retrieve package / asset versions. Everything works fine, until we try to use polish chars, like "ł".

For example, we have package named 'test3' and an asset (rule) called "wiek na podstawie PESEL - przedział 3" (name itself is unimportant, important is this "ł" in last word). Retrieving rest xml file for whole package we get a fragment like this:

```
<assets>
   http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/rest/packages/test3/asset/wiek%20na%20podstawie%20PESEL%20-%20przedział%203
</assets>
```

Asside from a Guvnor API's specific typo (it should be /test3/**assets**, not /test3/**asset**) this link doesn't work - browser automatically converted the "ł" to UTF-8 equivalent "%C5%82" and threw an error code that looks as if this page was not recognized by REST (incorrect asset name). The " "s works fine as "%20"s, the problem seems to be with the 16b characters.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: That is documented correct behavior for the browser. Apparently the server side is not configured correctly.

Comment: I figured that, browser automatically converts my "%C5%82"s in any urls to "ł"s, and I also read that Guvnor REST api is configured for UTF-8 charset only. But that still leaves us with drools assets that we are unable to locate with Guvnor REST api using standard methods. What I meant is is there a workaround to retrieve those assets, or maybe a way for Guvnor to forbid 16b chars in names?

Comment: I know Unicode, but I can't help you with Drools. Somewhere in there is an encoding setting, I'd have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a simple workaround. Instead of calling {rest-path}/packages/{package-name}/assets/{asset-name} to get the asset info, I call {rest-path}/packages/{package-name}/assets/, to get all the assets in a package.

This is good not only, cause it omits the http request that's not working, but also it avoids multiple requests, which in our case contributes towards proofing an application to race condition problem (when we retrieve all the asset version info and in time between requests someone rebuilds package in Guvnor).

Comment: What does this have to do with his character set woes?

Comment: Earlier I used an URL that had "ł" in asset-name part, and it wasn't recognized properly. After some reading I found out that Guvnor Rest API allows you to retrieve all the assets info without calling for it's name, so now the "ł" char is inside the xml file I get in the result.

Hence, it's not a 'solution', just a 'workaround' - but it works for me.